# Cannot sync scala project in IntelliJ IDEA Community 2019.2.4

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

Scala newbie here: I am attempting to get started with Scala using Windows 10 (Pro 10.0.18362 Build 18362) Hyper-v Quick Create of Ubuntu (18.04.3 LTS).  I installed the JRE and JDK (11.0.4).  I installed IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4.  I added the Plugin for Scala (plugin 2019.2.37).  I have left the SBT Executor 1.2.1 disabled for now: it was enabled earlier but it does not seem to affect the results.  I tried to create the HelloWorld application (see below).  I added the Scala Framework to the Project and, after encountering the error below, the Mavin framework (adding Mavin did not help.)  After correcting the error in bulid.sbt it looks like this:

```
import com.sun.tools.javac.resources.version 
name := "HelloWorld" 
version := "0.1" 
scalaVersion := "2.13.1"
```

I create a Scala worksheet by right-click on scala folder and selecting Scala Worksheet:

```
object Hello extends App {
println("Hello, World!")
}
```

I get a pop-up saying Maven project needs to be imported.  This succeeds quickly.  I get a second one saying sbt project needs to be imported.  This fails:

```
sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading org.scala-sbt:zinc-compile-core_2.12:1.3.1
```

and this error accompanies it:

```
not found: https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/org.scala-sbt/util-position_2.12/1.3.2/ivys/ivy.xml
```

The first ResolveException appears to be about a part of Mavin, but that should be present. This error message is followed by many other "not found" errors, but I assume they all stem from the above errors or are related. I cannot seem to find a solution: most of the information and examples on IntelliJ IDEA Scala on the web are several years (editions) out of date.

It appears Maven apps are to be deployed to Apache Spark.  Not my intention, but in the Mavin panel I can successfully clean, validate and compile.

When I Run the Hello.sc app, I get this:

```
/snap/intellij-idea-community/185/jbr/bin/java -javaagent:/snap/intellij-idea-community/185/lib/idea_rt.jar=37033:/snap/intellij-idea-community/185/bin -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /home/perfwise/ideaProjects/HelloWorld/target/classes:/home/perfwise/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/jars/scala-library-2.13.1.jar:/home/perfwise/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/jars/scala-reflect-2.13.1.jar:/home/perfwise/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-library/srcs/scala-library-2.13.1-sources.jar:/home/perfwise/.ivy2/cache/org.scala-lang/scala-reflect/srcs/scala-reflect-2.13.1-sources.jar Hello
Error: Could not find or load main class Hello
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Hello
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I would have expected this to work. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, you do not need to add Maven support for the SBT-based project in IDE. SBT already manages the dependencies of your project and builds it. It may cause IDE project's configuration conflicts if you use bot Maven and SBT. Also the sbt script the `import com.sun.tools.javac.resources.version` loks suspitions, why did you add this symbol from Java SDK? Try removing it and re-mport project in SBT tool window. Generally, you can use IDE to create SBT project - it will set up project structure and create build.sbt file to start with.

Comment: See also https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sbt-support.html

Comment: Very helpful notes, thanks.  Upon restart, I noticed a failure to connect to the WiFi on the Host.  Initially it was working as I had downloaded several packages. I reconfigured the Hyper-V by adding a new Virtual Switch connected directly to the laptop's modem instead of the default Kaspersky (anti-virus) proxy.  After linking the VM to this new Virtual Switch in Setting ==> Network Adapter, this solved the sbt sync problem described above.  However when I run the Hello.sc, I still get the above error: "Could not find or load main class "Hello".

Comment: OK, seemed to get past that problem of "Could not find..." by restarting IDEA.  One last (I hope) question: where does the output go?  I can't find "Hello, World!" anywhere.